# Как убрать конфликт кликов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**ВНИМАНИЕ**  [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwmXPP)

```
/**
 * Открытие и закрытие блока с формой авторизации
 */


function openHeaderAuth() {

    $('#js-open-auth-block').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var block = $(this).parent('.login');
        if (!block.hasClass('active')) {
            block.addClass('active');
            block.removeClass('hide');
            console.log(1);
        }
        else {
            block.addClass('hide');
            block.removeClass('active');
            console.log(2)
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Скрытие блока с формой авторизации при клике вне его области
 */

function closeAuthBlock() {
    var block = $('div.login');

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if (block.hasClass('active')) {
            if (!($(e.target).hasClass('login'))) {
                block.addClass('hide');
                block.removeClass('active');
                console.log(3)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Нужно реализовать, что бы блок с формой закрывался при клике и на "личный кабинет", и когда клик вне его. Все готово, но при клике на Личный Кабинет при открытой форме она не закрывается, так как сначала срабатывает закрытие и тут же открытие.

Буду благодарен советам

Comment: А можно просмотреть и саму вёрстку?

Comment: может как-то так : https://jsfiddle.net/CRafT/L6yxp3cu/

Comment: @MOjito Кодпен же есть

Comment: @C.Raf.T А что вы изменили? Не вижу

Comment: добавил классы к элементам div и класс для "личного кабинетa"

Comment: @C.Raf.T спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, не нужен класс hide, он всего-лишь повторяет свойства, которые есть в определении блока и так.

Функцию closeAuthBlock() надо переделать, в данный момент она закрывается при фокусе на инпуте, что делает невозможным использование формы.

```
function closeAuthBlock() {
  var block = $('div.login');

  $(document).click(function (e) {
    if (block.hasClass('active')) {
        if ( !$(e.target).closest('.login').length ) {
            block.removeClass('active');
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Функцию openHeaderAuth() можно сократить до вида:

```
function openHeaderAuth() {
  $('#js-open-auth-block').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var block = $(this).parent('.login');

    block.toggleClass('active');
  });
}
```

Как это работает: каждый клик по кнопке `#js-open-auth-block` включает-выключает класс active (`function openHeaderAuth()` ); клик вне блока выключает класс active (`function openHeaderAuth()` ).

Comment: Чудеса в решете! Почему у меня перекрывалось, а у вас нет? У меня же вроде как то же самое было, но более громоздко расписано
.hide уже был от  безысходства)

Comment: Всё дело в методе `toggleClass` — у вас были сложные условия, которые действовали одновременно, а сейчас клик по кнопке работает отдельно, как и клик по остальному документу.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko нет, дело не в нем. Дело в вызове `closest`

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов потому что вы проверяли класс у `e.target` напрямую, а тут идет проверка по всей цепочке родителей

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, используйте одно и то же событие, не надо использовать в одном месте `click`, а в другом - `mouseup`.

Во-вторых, используйте `e.stopPropagation()` чтобы отменить срабатывание второго обработчика на то же самое событие.

В-третьих, узнайте про функцию [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: 1) Почему?

2 и 3 спасибо, не знал

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов потому что с помощью `stopPropagation` можно прервать только то событие, которое было обработано

Comment: Понял, спасибо еще раз, все заработало